# Use custom Alias for Acronym in glossaries package?

Tags: glossaries

I am trying to put together an acronym list for my thesis using the package glossaries. However, in some cases I need to use a different grammar form of the item (German is a little complicated...) which is not equal to the singular or plural form.

The general question is: Is there a way to define a custom alias form of the item in-text WITHOUT affecting the detection of whether or not the acronym has already been introduced?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[acronym,shortcuts,toc]{glossaries} % Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{EZM}{EZM}{extrazelluläre Matrix}

\begin{document}
In der \ac{EZM} befindet sich xyz. Die \ac{EZM} ist weiterhin xyz.
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\end{document}
```

The text output is:

> In der extrazelluläre Matrix (EZM) befindet sich xyz. Die EZM ist
>   weiterhin xyz.

The glossary output is:

> EZM extrazelluläre Matrix. 1

The glossary output is fine, but I would like my text output to look like this:

> In der extrazelluläre**n** Matrix (EZM) befindet sich xyz. Die EZM ist
>   weiterhin xyz.

(Note: there is an extra "n" in "extrazellulären")

Ideas?

Comment: I used `acronym` rather than `glossaries` hence I can only hint.  But I would clone the plural form macros from the original .sty file to form dative (IIRC, my German was a long time ago) singular and plural equivalents.  This would extend to other cases if required.

Comment: @ChrisH Good idea. I added an 'alias' field using `\glsaddkey`. By then using the command `\glsalias{EZM}` I got the correct result (dative, indeed!), but the output was 'in der extrazellulären Matrix befindet...', so 'EZM' was missing and when I called the acronym for the second time using `\gls{EZM}` it printed 'Die extrazelluläre Matrix (EZM) ist...' although here it should only say 'Die EZM ist...'. How can I use the `\glsaddkey` command in combination with first use flag?

Answer (score 2):

I got it to work using this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{xspace}

\glsaddkey
 {alternative}% key
 {}% default value
 {\glsentryalternative}% no link cs
 {\Glsentryalternative}% no link ucfirst cs
 {\glsalternative}% link cs
 {\Glsalternative}% link ucfirst cs
 {\GLSalternative}% link all caps cs

\newcommand{\glslongalias}[1]{%
  \ifglsused{#1}{\glsalternative{#1}}{\glsalternative{#1} (\glsentrytext{#1})\glsunset{#1}}\xspace
}

\newacronym[
    alternative={extrazellulären Matrix}
]{EZM}{EZM}{extrazelluläre Matrix}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

In der \glslongalias{EZM} befindet sich xyz. Die \gls{EZM} ist weiterhin xyz.

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```